# Simple Vyatta configuration / BGP routes not injecting into routing table

Tags: networking, bgp, vyatta

I have a exceptionally simple setup I'm playing with however I'm banging my head against the wall as to why it's not working.

Right now I have two Vyatta routers (R1, R2) connected locally. Both are connected via a cross connect. I've setup a BGP session between the two - that's working as intended. There is no route-maps / policies in place. I'm simply trying to advertise a single route from R1 to R2 via BGP (I'm not using any IGP yet, merely a static route).

Everything is seemingly working as it's supposed to - R1 and R2 have a BGP session open and R2 see's the routes R1 is attempting to advertise:

```
vyatta@R2# run show ip bgp neighbors 10.0.50.10 received-routes
BGP table version is 5, local router ID is 10.0.60.10
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 10.0.2.0/24      10.0.50.10                             0 1 i

Total number of prefixes 1
```

Now the problem is that's just routes it's seeing however it's not actively adding it to the routing table. Running *show ip bgp* will list nothing as well as *show ip bgp neighbor 10.0.50.10 routes*. R2 *can* access the next hop (R1) at 10.0.50.10.

Am I missing something terribly obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume You are advertising for example route 192.168.1.0/24 from R1.
R1 needs to have this route installed in its routing table.

So You need to have any of these for example:
- an interface that is actually UP with IP from 192.168.1.0/24. If it is DOWN (no link) You will not get that route advertised via BGP. (Why advertise something if interface is down?)
- a route to 192.168.1.0/24 to null0 may force it to advertise it
- 192.168.1.0/24 in routing table from any other source like a static entry, and entry from another protocol like ospf.

reassuming: **BGP will not advertise something (network) that doesn't exist in *your* routing table.**

Comment: I've added a static route on R1 so it did advertise the route over BGP. I can confirm by checking the "show ip bgp neighbor 10.0.60.10 advertised-routes" command. R2 is also receiving those routes by checking the "show ip bgp neighbor 10.0.50.10 received-routes". However those routes are not being placed in the routing table in R2. There is no route-map / policy enabled on R2 at this time.

Comment: @WinkyWolly: Please post both from R1 and R2 - 1. show ip bgp summary  2. show ip route 3. show ip bgp

Comment: It may be worth noting I'm now advertising from R2 -> R1 as I was trying to see if I can get it working. The 10.0.60.0/24 route is advertised but not being shown in R1's routing table. http://pastie.org/private/f0huvqpxz3gea54akkxiww

Comment: @WinkyWolly I have strong impression that something very important and obvious is missing in Your config. Can You post Full config from R2 ?

Comment: I concur! Here is the relevant configuration from R2 - I only excluded things such as users / system stuff (NTP, etc). There are no active policies on either router. http://pastie.org/private/mtyeq0mthkkmneawhyhddq