# Vyatta (Brocade) receives BGP routes, but doesn't show in routing table

Tags: networking, bgp, vyatta, brocade

What would be the reason for Brocade vRouter to receive BGP routes, identify them as valid and best, but not use in the routing table?

*show ip bgp neighbors 169.254.5.1 received-routes
*> 10.2.0.0/16      169.254.5.1                            0 65500 7224 i*

but nothing for 10.2.0.0/16 in *show ip route*

The router can reach 169.254.5.1

The same peer (Cisco CSR) advertises routes successfully to other neighbors, including some Vyatta flavors (Ubiquiti).

I saw this post with similar question, but it doesn't answer it:
[Simple Vyatta configuration / BGP routes not injecting into routing table](https://serverfault.com/questions/570307/simple-vyatta-configuration-bgp-routes-not-injecting-into-routing-table)

Comment: Works once I change the ASs so it becomes iBGP!
What do I miss on the eBGP configuration? What should be different other than ASs?

Comment: Is this tunnel over a GRE? set protocols bgp <asn> neighbor <ip> ebgp-multihop 2